# Cómo configurar un CronJob Symfony3

Tags: symfony3, controller

¿Cómo creo un cronjob en symfony3 para un controlador determinado? Necesito se ejecute cada 30 minutos.

la ruta de la acción del controlador es '/update'

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

class UpdateCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
        ->setName('app:update:products')
        ->setDescription('Update de Productos')
        ;
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln([
        'Inicio de Actualización',
        '============>',
        '',
        ]);
        $path = get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web';
        $finder = new Finder();
        $finder->files()->in($path);
        $finder->name('productos.txt');
        foreach ($finder as $file) {
            $contents = $file->getContents();
            $arrayContents = str_getcsv($contents,'
            ');
            //var_dump($arrayContents);
            foreach ($arrayContents as $dato){
                    $datos= str_getcsv($dato,' ');
                    var_dump($datos);
                }
            }
        $client = new SoapClient('https://example_wsdl.php?v=01.02');
        $synchro = $client->__soapCall(
            'Sincronizacion',
            [[
                'param1'=> xxxx,
                'param2'=>'xxxx',
                'param3' => 'xxxx'
            ]]
        );
        var_export($sinchro);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Podrías ser mas específico? Ya tiene el cronjob y quieres ejecutarlo cada 30 minutos o no lo tienes hecho y a parte quieres que se ejecute cada 30 minutos

Comment: Tengo el controlador hecho y como es una consulta a un webservice quisiera que se realice cada 30 minutos esa consulta. No se como se instala ni configura un cronjob en symfony3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un [link](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/) de la documentación de crontask, aún así te lo explico un poco a groso modo.

- **Para configurar un cronjob/crontask necesitaras crear un nuevo directorio al nivel de Controller/Entity, y crear allí un documento Command y al igual que los demás en tu caso seria ClientCommand**
- Te adjunto un ejemplo de como debería ir el archivo ClientCommand aún así te recomiendo que leas la documentación para mas información

```
class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('devvness:my_command')
            ->setDescription('Descripción de lo que hace el comando')
            ->addArgument('my_argument', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Explicamos el significado del argumento');
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        // Hacemos lo que sea
        $output->writeln('Hola mundo');
        $em->flush();
    }
}

/30* * * * * php /Ruta/Absoluta/Hasta/Proyecto/Symfony/app/consoledevness:mycommand --myargument=valor
```

Esto lo actualizaria cada 30 min, tienes que ejecutar ese comando, si pones la `/` delante del 30 (minutos) lo ejecutará cada 30 minutos, si no la pones lo ejecutará a los 30 minutos una vez

Comment: Muchas gracias Alberto leo la documentación y comento los resultados!

Comment: Modifico El cuerpo de la preguta con el command... pero no me funciona.

Comment: Donde debo indicarle el tiempo para ejecutarse?

Comment: @Nicoo1991 respuesta actualizada

Comment: En ubuntu 16.04 no me permite poner  /30 me indica que está mal la syntaxs pero dejándolo proramado paraun horario definido sería 30 5 * * * * php /Ruta/Absoluta/Hasta/Proyecto/Symfony/app/consoledevness:mycommand --myargument=valor

Comment: Luego de guardar el archivo crontab es necesario eecutarlo por primera vez?

Comment: @Nicoo1991 si, necesitas ejecutarlo por primera vez

Comment: Funcionando OK.Muchas Gracias @Alberto Martinez

Comment: @Nicoo1991 siento no haberte respondido ni antes ni mejor, me alegro que te funcione!